# Sending a message to a number of connection-oriented sockets without using loops

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, ipc

This is a question that appeared in one past exam of my college and I am not at all understanding how to do it. It involves reading data from a bunch of processes which are connected to the central process via different kinds of IPC mechanisms( pipes, FIFO, one is used with popen).The central process is also listening to two connection-oriented sfds. The main challenge of this question is to send the data read from the former processes to **ALL** the clients using `send()` system call **only once** and that too without loops.

The second pitfall in this question in this question is the echo server E. The central process passes one client to E after getting a signal from another process P4. Afterwards that client is served by E.

The problem statement of the question is very complicated, that's why I could not explain it with clarity. So, I am providing the pic of the actual question,please go through it for clarity:

[image]
I have two main questions:

1. How to send a message to all recipients using connection oriented sockets?
2. How to pass a file descriptor to other (unrelated) process.

Comment: I feel this is way to broad a question.

Comment: @alk any way of approaching?

Comment: @Ricky when using connection-oriented sockets (TCP, etc), you simply can't call `send()` one time and have it deliver to multiple recipients, they are 1-to-1 and require individual `send()` calls. The only way a single `send()` call can deliver to multiple recipients is by using message-oriented sockets (UDP, etc) with subnet broadcasts or IP multicasting.